# IE10: Touch scrolling over anchors not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, scroll, touch, internet-explorer-10

IE 10 doesn't scroll the page when we touch and scroll over an anchor.

The problem is that we have web app for mobile devices using jQueryMobile, and in certain pages, almost all the screen is filled with anchors. Users with IE10 cannot easily scroll the page to see the bottom options. All other devices and OSs work properly.

We have tried with different options of -ms-touch-action but haven't managed to make touch&scroll over an anchor.

We have been looking for -ms-touch-action examples and haven't found any useful.

thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue.  My workmate finally found out that in our case it's connected to the CSS property `-ms-touch-action: none;`.

He didn't want to have these grey boxes around the anchors, which IE automatically does when you hover over the links, so he set the CSS property `-ms-touch-action: none;`.

But exactly this caused the problem you have above. When he removed the full CSS command `-ms-touch-action`, it worked.